# Problema component.html Angular 4

Tags: angularjs

Estou com um pequeno problema, comecei os estudos em Angular, ainda estou entendendo o funcionamento dos **modules, componentes e services**. Porém quando coloco uma estrutura html no component.html, ele simplesmente não mostra nada na pagina, se eu apago essa estrutura e coloco apenas uma **div** com bootstrap, ele mostra na tela. Como consigo resolver isso ? **Ja peguei a tag do seletor e coloquei no app.component.html**

```html
   Div com bootstrap sendo mostrada em tela.

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <p>teste</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

```html
Estrutura html que não aparece em tela, localizada no teste.component.html. Exp:

<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>Page Title</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="main.css" />
  <script src="main.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
<p>Teste</p>
</body>
</html>>
```

Comment: O seu `app.component.html` tem um elemento `<router-output>` no body? As rotas estão corretas? Como está definido o componente com problema? Vou precisar de mais código.

Answer (score -2):

Aparentemente em seu código tem um > a mais no final do `</html>>` remova e tente novamente, sendo que esse teste.component.html não precisa de `<html> <head>` ... porque isso já tem na index.html, é um cógido que será adicionado no meio da página, uma injeção do HTML ...

Comment: Você tem reputação suficiente pra colocar comentários nas outras perguntas e faz uma resposta com o texto de um comentário?

Comment: Isto não fornece uma resposta à pergunta. Para criticar ou solicitar esclarecimento de um autor, deixe um comentário abaixo da publicação dele. - [Da Revisão](/review/low-quality-posts/183132)

Comment: @rbz refiz a resposta, foi mal pelo comentário na resposta.